# How to stay calm for a 7 minute scientific research talk?

Tags: presentation

As I wrote few days ago, maybe someone remembers, I am waiting for a date to be set up and to present my scientific research on the Congress.
I have never done this before, they give me 7mins to show my introduction, aim, material and methods, results, discussion, conclusion and literature.
The research is huge but my main problem is being nervous and too emotional. Does any of you have any tips how to make myself more relaxed and somehow bring myself to state "its gonna be ok"?
My main problem is my **devotion** to the subject since there is some molestation and neglecting recorded and law violation. It is very hard for me to stay "normal".
I would appreciate any advice 
Thank you, all.

Comment: In my field (mathematics) a 7-minute talk would probably consist of introduction and results, probably not even all of the results. If it's possible in our field, I'd suggest doing only those and omitting the rest of your list (aim, material and methods, discussion, conclusion, and literature review), though perhaps something about your aim could be in the introduction and some discussion might accompany the results.

Comment: I read your question as saying your presentation starts in 7 minutes, and I was quite alarmed. I'm glad you have more time than that to prepare!

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "since there is some molestation and neglecting recorded and law violation." If there are any issues regarding sexual assault, video recordings, or concerns about criminal laws related to a talk, those are quite different from the first part of the question and might require more specific guidance.  There is no need to respond with details about your specific case if it makes you feal uncomfortably, but I'm concerned that you won't get very useful answers here if this is an important part of your question.

Comment: The research is about Animal Welfare and Law has been violated. For me, it is very sensitive topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution to worry is work.  Write your speech. Practice it at least three times.  Treat the practice as if you were actually giving the talk.

Answer (score 17):

(For context: I am a mathematician in the U.S.) For many reasons, I make my research students "rehearse" their presentations many, many times. It is of course all the more challenging to have a ridiculously short time in which to say anything. So, yes, crazy choices must be made. A more experienced person could coach/advise you on what to leave out.

Crazily-enough one of my students has won some presentation prizes for super-short talks by ... as she and I said to each other... "leaving out all the math". Definitely as opposed to trying to cram toooo much in.

Do not think in terms of giving a lecture for students. The only sane way to give such a short presentation is to think in terms of addressing people who already know enough so that the *new* parts of your work can stand on their own. It is obviously impossible to explain almost anything at all. No "background" on basic grad-level material. No time!

So, absolutely, find a more senior person to "rehearse" with. Your own peers may not have a clear-enough idea of what should be included to really help you. "Experts know what experts know."

(And, to be clear, rehearse the talk over and over and over and over... with your coach/advisor/critic... until you can do it in your sleep, etc.)

Comment: Doesn't relate but I always feel that maths (and also physics) lectures or talks are the best where maths is neglected as far as possible. These are the most vivid and sustainable lectures.

Answer (score 3):

**Practice makes perfect.**  First practice your speech over and over again in the privacy of your own office, with no-one watching.  Make sure you have the length and speed of your speech right, so that you are not rushing through it.  Once you feel you have it right, practice it several times in front of some trusted colleagues, and make any necessary changes based on feedback.  Practice it enough times to get used to presenting while nervous, and get used to the feeling of "butterflies in your stomach".  Ideally, this repetition will allow you to commit most of your speech to memory, and get you used to speaking to an audience on a topic that is sensitive to you.  If you are to speak in a large venue, it can also help to go there in the morning before anyone is there (assuming you can get in) and get yourself used to the space.  Try standing where you will stand and looking out over the empty venue.  That way it will be a bit more familiar to you when you do your speech.

Answer (score 3):

Probably too late for your talk, but you might profit for your next time: Learn from other presenters. When you visit the conference, a lot of talks will be 7 min in length. Try to concentrate how others are presenting their work:

- How do they split their rare minutes to introductions, maths, results, and outlook?
- How deep do they dive into their topics and their specific terms, methods etc.?
- If you like a talk, ask yourself whether it was the topic, the presenter, or something you could adapt to your next talk. Similar if you dislike a talk, can you identify why you disliked it and whether you can avoid such things for your talk?

If you know people on the conference and they attend your talk, you can ask them to provide constructive criticism. Either in talk or via email.

This will boost your confidence and thus keep you calmer next time.

Comment: This might be useful, but most people give terrible talks. Better advice might be to reflect on your favorite 3 talks and try to emulate those.